# Codeigniter website not working on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I downloaded a website from my live server. I want to run it on my localhost. I changed the `base_url` to my localhost url but this is not working. This is my `config.php`.

Live Site:

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://my_site/portal/';

LocalHost:

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/limo/portal/';

This is my `.HTACCESS`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /portal/

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /portal/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me as this is my very first project in codeigniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `RewriteBase` to `/limo/portal/` and remove `/portal/` from the last `RewriteRule`.